# OFDM system capacity if we double the subcarriers

Tags: ofdm, capacity

Suppose we have two OFDM based systems A & B.

- System A has $N$ subcarriers and bandwidth $W$, and the number of samples in the CP is 10% of $N$.
- System B has $2N$ subcarriers, $2W$ bandwidth and the number of samples in the CP is 5% of $2N$.

Which system has higher capacity?

Comment: Guessing this is some sort of homework question, have you tried answering it yourself first? If so, you should post where you are in your reasoning at least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the data rate of ofdm depends on number of subcarriers](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84049/does-the-data-rate-of-ofdm-depends-on-number-of-subcarriers)

Comment: (my answer there addresses all the aspects in your homework/exam problem: changing number of subcarriers, changing procentual length of CP, bandwidth)

Comment: Can be solved the above questions by using data rate= bandwidth * spectral efficiency ?

Comment: The question is actually from an interview.

Answer (score 1):

The capacity of $A$ is $W\log_2(1+\text{snr})/1.1/NW$

The capacity of $B$ is $2W\log_2(1+\text{snr}/2)/1.05/NW$

So the capacity of $B$ is larger than that of $A$.